# Bokeh server slow to render lots of NaN values (but fast enough in notebook)

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

I am trying to build a dashboard using bokeh, and am currently stuck on a large line plot like this one:

### [image: The plot]

Even though this plots fairly quickly in my jupiter notebook (around a second maybe) it takes forever (multiple minutes) in my bokeh server. the network tab in my debug console shows no new data being received during this time, so I would guess it can't be my python code blocking the rendering?

I also have a checkboxgroup, and it again takes more than a minute before the callback even reaches the bokeh server.

I am plotting 40,000+ line segments connected and interspersed with loads of NaN values in 7 lines. (As I believe plotting large lines is better than plotting many lines in bokeh?).

I make my plot like this:

```
f = figure(toolbar_location=None, title='Schade verloop over leeftijd', output_backend="webgl")
f.xaxis.axis_label = 'Leeftijd'
f.yaxis.axis_label = 'Schade'
for i, col, lbl in zip(range(7), colors, labels):
    r = f.line(x='x_line', y='y_line', line_width=2, source=sources[i], line_color=col, legend=lbl)
f.legend.location = "top_left"
f.legend.click_policy = "hide"
```

And a small subsection of my data:

```
xs = [np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
 np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
 np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
 np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
 np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
 np.array([np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,
           np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,11.18082192, 12.02739726, 13.25205479, 14.22739726,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,  6.55616438,  7.53150685,  8.52054795,
         9.47123288, 10.44109589,np.nan]),
np.array([np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,  0.70410959,  1.63835616,
         2.73972603,  3.64931507,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,  4.00821918,  5.04383562,  6.00821918,  7.05479452,
        np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,  4.56164384,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,11.18082192,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,  5.94794521,  6.55616438,  7.53150685,  8.52054795,
        np.nan,np.nan,np.nan])]

ys = [np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
 np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
 np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
 np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
 np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
        np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
 np.array([        np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,
                np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,
                np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,
                np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,
                np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,
                np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,
                np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,
        -0.15652901,  0.14953203,  0.62195036,  0.64414847,         np.nan,
                np.nan,         np.nan, -0.33739475, -0.27092199, -0.32020045,
        -0.35019554, -0.21857558,         np.nan]),
 np.array([        np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan, -0.42062806, -0.50175937,
        -0.39375614, -0.45259168,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,
                np.nan, -0.38755729, -0.45590074, -0.38985249, -0.30375873,
                np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan, -0.10799712,
                np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,
                np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,
                np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,
        -0.15652901,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan,
                np.nan, -0.2219407 , -0.33739475, -0.27092199, -0.32020045,
                np.nan,         np.nan,         np.nan])]
```

Which is put into a ColumnDataSource like this:

```
single_sources = [ColumnDataSource({'x_line': xs[i], 'y_line': ys[i]}) for i in range(7)]
```

my general structure:
**main.py:**

```
tab1 = Lineplot_Tab()
tabs = Tabs(tabs=[tab1])
curdoc().add_root(tabs)
curdoc().title = 'Dos dashboard'
```

**Lineplot_Tab.py**

```
def Lineplot_tab():
    # Some stuff with setting constants
    # And loading some general data (pretty large I guess)

    def make_full_dataset(checkboxselection):
        # Loads sizable data based on the selection in the checkboxes,
        # finally returns the ColumnDataSources

    def make_plot(sources):
        # The code for making the figure (as above)

    def update():
        plot_data_new, _, _ = make_full_dataset(checkbox_selection)
        for i in range(7):
            plot_data[i].data = plot_data_new[i].data

    active = [0]
    weg_selector = CheckboxGroup(labels=wegen, active=active)
    weg_selector.on_change('active', update)

    wegen_selectie = [wegen[i] for i in weg_selector.active]
    plot_data, colors, labels = make_full_dataset(wegen_selectie)

    p = make_plot(plot_data, colors, labels)

    controls = WidgetBox(weg_selector)
    layout = row(controls, p)

    tab = Panel(child=layout, title='Schadeverloop')
    return tab
```

I am running the server like:

```
bokeh serve --show --allow-websocket-origin=* --websocket-max-message-size=52428800000  dashboard
```

Hopefully someone sees what I am doing wrong from this, I would love to be able to use Bokeh to build this dashboard!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, so for anyone finding this later:

The large number of consecutive NaN values are in fact a problem (something about how the plot is rendered I am guessing). I created my dataset using a filter over a pandas dataframe and then turning this into a numpy array with a NaN tacked on the back to create seperate lines.
To reduce the number of NaN's I simply dropped the rows in Pandas that contained no usefull values.

```
vals = vals.dropna(axis=0,how='all')
```

While this does not remove all consecutive NaN values on all rows, it significantly reduced the amount and helped a lot in rendering times. (from multiple minutes to around a second)

I realise this is a pretty specific solution for me, but either way, NaN's in plotting apperently DO count as datapoints!

Stil interesting this is not an issue in the jupyter notebook.

Comment: I remember in older versions of Bokeh you had to replace the NaN values in a pandas dataframe with the string "nan" if you did not want it to graph that coordinate. So you would have to do df['colname'].fillna(value="nan",inplace=True)